# What makes living beings alive?

Tags: life

To clarify, I'm not asking about the common properties of living organisms, such as reproducing and having a metabolism, etc. What I'm curious about is, what is the difference between organic molecules and actual living beings?

For example, if a person's heart stops beating, they are technically dead, but all the chemical compounds and molecules are still there.. I guess another approach to this question would be "If we bring together all the atoms of a living being in the same exact arrangement, would that new thing be alive?"

Comment: organic compounds are carbon based molecules. Living being contains several properties, some of which you have named!

Comment: I don't think you can ignore the common properties of living organisms (or the definition of organism) if you want to talk about *life*. Someone whose heart has stopped is no longer alive because they can't deliver oxygen to their cells any longer for metabolism to occur.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I understand that, but what separates what was alive just a minute ago from the dead state of it? I just can't wrap my head around how these seemingly ordinary chemical compounds get together and do things with a purpose (which is to not die and to reproduce I guess).

Comment: The minute a *critical* component stops functioning, the organism dies. That's why the definition of organism counts. For a highly complex organism, it has to be that organism, not all the cells which make it up. This can go on and on. If the cell membrane integrity of a single celled organism is lost, it dies. But what if enzymatic processes are still going on before cell lysis? Is that protein alive? No, it's not. Similarly, a person's death is not negated by how long it takes for all of his cells to stop metabolizing.

Comment: @anongoodnurse That's a pretty good explanation. Thanks a lot